# Creating a summary column of if another column is present

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I am wanting to creat a column showing the combination of if other columns are present, this is best explained as an example:

```
##random data
Data <- data.frame(
    a = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    b = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    c = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    d = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE)
) 

##this creates a table like this

| a  | b  | c  | d  |
| :- |: - | :- |: - |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  |
| 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  |
| 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
| 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |
| 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |
| 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  |
| 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
| 0  |0   | 1  | 1  |

##I wish to add a column on the end saying if a 1 is present with a space, for instance:

| a  | b  | c  | d  |together  |
| :- |: - | :- |: - |          |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  |d         |
| 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  |b d       |
| 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  |c d       |
| 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |None      |
| 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |b c       |
| 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |b c       |
| 0  | 1  | 1  | 0  |b c       |
| 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  |a b c     |
| 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  |a         |
| 0  |0   | 1  | 1  |c d       |
```

Does any one have any code for this? I have tried with if else functions, or coding it as 0010 = c, 0001 = d but with 8 variables in the real dataset this is quite a lot!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Base R you could do:

```
cbind(df, together=apply(df, 1, function(x)paste(names(df)[x>0], collapse = ' ')))
   a b c d together
1  0 0 0 1        d
2  0 1 0 1      b d
3  0 0 1 1      c d
4  0 0 0 0         
5  0 1 1 0      b c
6  0 1 1 0      b c
7  0 1 1 0      b c
8  1 1 1 0    a b c
9  1 0 0 0        a
10 0 0 1 1      c d
```

or even:

```
df$together <- NULL # NOT NECESSARY
idx <- which(df>0, TRUE)   
n <- tapply(names(df)[idx[,2]], idx[,1],paste, collapse = ' ')
df[names(n), 'together'] <- n

df
# A tibble: 10 × 5
       a     b     c     d together
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
 1     0     0     0     1 d       
 2     0     1     0     1 b d    
 3     0     0     1     1 c d    
 4     0     0     0     0 NA      
 5     0     1     1     0 b c    
 6     0     1     1     0 b c    
 7     0     1     1     0 b c    
 8     1     1     1     0 a b c 
 9     1     0     0     0 a       
10     0     0     1     1 c d
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2311)

Data <- data.frame(
  a = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  b = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  c = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  d = sample(c("0", "1"), 10, replace = TRUE)
) 

Data %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(
    together = paste(
      names(.)[which(c_across(everything()) == 1L)],
      collapse = ' '
    ),
    together = replace(together, together == '', 'None')
  )
```

Output (the test set is different as you haven't set the seed):

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
# Rowwise: 
   a     b     c     d     together
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
 1 0     0     1     1     c d     
 2 1     0     0     0     a       
 3 0     0     0     0     None    
 4 1     1     1     0     a b c   
 5 1     1     0     0     a b     
 6 1     1     0     1     a b d   
 7 0     0     0     1     d       
 8 1     0     0     0     a       
 9 0     1     0     0     b       
10 0     1     0     1     b d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Data %>%
   mutate(across(everything(),
    ~ case_match(.x, 1 ~ cur_column()), .names = "{.col}_new")) %>% 
   unite(together, ends_with("_new"), sep = " ", na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 5
       a     b     c     d together
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
 1     0     0     0     1 "d"     
 2     0     1     0     1 "b d"   
 3     0     0     1     1 "c d"   
 4     0     0     0     0 ""      
 5     0     1     1     0 "b c"   
 6     0     1     1     0 "b c"   
 7     0     1     1     0 "b c"   
 8     1     1     1     0 "a b c" 
 9     1     0     0     0 "a"     
10     0     0     1     1 "c d"
```

#### data

```
Data <- structure(list(a = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), b = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), c = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1), d = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```